# Having a JSON parse error in receiving json data

Tags: java, json, spring

Hi I am trying to send a JSON array from a POST to Spring backend.

In my Javascript:

```
$('#tblfilelisting tbody tr').each(function () {
        var namerecord = {
            No: $(this).find('.assignindex').text().trim(),
            Name: $(this).find('.getname').val(),
            File: $(this).find('.getfilename').text().trim(),
            Status: $(this).find('.radioname:checked').val()
        };
        nameList.push(namerecord);
    });

    var jasonData = new FormData();
    jasonData.append('arrStr', JSON.stringify(nameList));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/CheckValidateBeforeSave',
        data: jasonData,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            //
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.code != '200') {
                return false;
            }
            var get = data.jasonResult;
            for (var i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
                appendResultResponse(get.No[i], get.Name[i], get.File[i], get.Status[i], get.Result[i]);
                appendErrorMess(get.No[i], get.hasDuplicated[i]);
            }
            $('#uploadFileConfirmation').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //
        },
    });
```

In my REST Controller, I have:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/CheckValidateBeforeSave", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public FileManagement CheckValidateBeforeSave(@RequestBody FileManagement fileManagement) {
        fileManagementService.checkMultipleFiles(fileManagement);
        return fileManagement;
    }
```

But the error that I got was : 
JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value

But my POST request does not have - sign:

------WebKitFormBoundaryId7kxO7B9rozEwHv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="arrStr"

[{"No":"1","Name":"dd","File":"Test PDF 2.pdf","Status":"on"}]
------WebKitFormBoundaryId7kxO7B9rozEwHv--
line-awesome.woff2?v=1.1.   CheckValidateBeforeSave common.js   util.js AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2F…zaSyBTGnKT7dt597vo9QgeQ7BFhvSRP4eiMSM&token=29026

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: do not use `FormData`, just set the `data` of the ajax to the JSON string

Comment: The json you provided is not well formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `JSON parse error` is that you are not actually sending a data of JSON format. Instead, your data have FormData format.

There are two ways you can fix it.

**1. You only need to send the nameList**

```
data: JSON.stringify(nameList)
```

**2. You want to send it as FormData (optionally along with other data)**

```
data:  {formdata: jasonData, var2: "other data"}
```